# Extraer texto entre etiqueta <br>

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

El problema al que me enfrento es que usualmente extraigo texto con `getText()`, sin embargo, en esta ocasión el texto se encuentra entre etiquetas `<br>` y no sé cómo extraerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esa línea de código obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero extraer el `bene siamo` ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para compartir el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No hay que extraer nada. Borra los `<br />`.